# Finding F ' (y)

Tags: integration

This question looks deceivingly simple to me so I was wondering if someone out there could enlighten me whether it really is what I think it is or if I have completely missed the point.
Let $$F(y) = \int^1_0 f(x,y) dx$$

$$
f(x,y)=
\left\{ 
\begin{array}{c}
\sin{xy},\,\, x\ne 0 \\ 
y,\,\, x=0 \\ 
\end{array}
\right. 
$$

Find $F ' (y).$

The way I see it is that by the fundamental theory of calculus $F'(y)=f(x,y)$.
However since the interval $ [0,1]$ needs to be considered, I think, I don't know what to do.
Anybody able to help me out here? It's such an annoyingly simple-looking question it's bugging me

Comment: When do $f(x,y)=\sin(xy)$ and when $f(x,y)=y$? I think your question is incomplete! Please try to complete it so you can get help

Comment: It's not $f(x,y)$ though

Comment: Whoops, it's fixed, thanks for noticing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of this problem is to mess with your mind a bit. Think about it: For each fixed $y,$ you have an integrand equal to $\sin(xy), x\in (0,1],$ and something else when $x=0.$ It doesn't matter what you defined it to be at $x=0.$ You could define $f(0,y)$ to be an arbitrary function of $y$ and you'd get the same answer coming out of the integral.

So just do the integral $\int_0^1 \sin (xy)\,dx.$ You'll get a function of $y$ from that. Then differentiate that.

PS: No, the FTC does not give what you wrote.

Answer (score 2):

Using [Leibnitz integral rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

$$F'(y) = \int_0^1 \frac{\partial}{\partial y} f(x,y) \,dx $$